git merge is blocked with Bitbucket DataCenter
I am having issue to merge a PR with Bitbucket Data Center.
Here is the sequence :

Another user created a Branch-A from master early.

"commit1" is committed to branch-A 6 days ago.

I created my branch-B from latest master (without commit1 in Branch-A) two days ago:
         Git checkout master
         Git pull
         Git checkout -b Branch-B


branch-A is merged into master with commit1 yesterday.

Today, I committed "commit2" into branch-B. when I tries to merge branch-B into master with "fast-forward only", I got error


"The merge could not be completed because the repository is configured to require fast-forward merges and the target branch contains commits which are not present in the source branch"
Of course commit1 is not in my branch, since when I checked out, it's not merged into master yet.
It looks like bitbucket is using commit1's commit date to judge if the merge is allowed or not.
Is this supposed to happen? I would think it should use commit1 's merged date.

Found the answer myself.
It actually doesn't matter the merged date or commit date, if the repo is configured to only allow FF-only, then it will block PR merge if any new commit is missing in source branch.
I need to rebase the source branch from target branch, then merge PR. I was worried I might need to re-ask PR approval, but that's not the case.
